# Two Column DIVs that expand with content inside

Tags: css, html, height

I'm trying to create a page with two divs inside a content div to act as columns. While I understand that this is a question that is often asked here, the difference is, I need the left side to be a title for the corresponding content on the right, but the content on the right will differentiate in height, and I need this to affect where the next title below on the left will appear.

Below is an image of how I want this to work, and how I'm guessing it can be done?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY8bt.png

Currently I'm doing this with HTML tables, which we all know is messy!

Many thanks in advance!

Dylan

Comment: put ur code or make fiddle

Comment: As I said, it was a simple HTML table, that's it. Didn't think I'd need to add that since everyone knows what it intails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without table, we can do it like this:

```
<div id="master">
    <div class="title">TITLE A</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac velit risus. Donec et libero erat. Pellentesque eros libero, lobortis eu diam accumsan, commodo tincidunt diam. Integer nec tincidunt dui.</div>
    <div class="magicClear"></div>
    <div class="title">TITLE B</div>
    <div class="content">Tiny content with tiny height</div>
    <div class="magicClear"></div>
    <div class="title">TITLE C</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac velit risus. Donec et libero erat. Pellentesque eros libero, lobortis eu diam accumsan, commodo tincidunt diam. Integer nec tincidunt dui.</div>
    <div class="magicClear"></div>
</div>
```

css :

```
#master {
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
}
.title {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.content {
    width: 450px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.magicCLear {
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djedjex/GU7RW/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
table
{
    border:none;
}
table td:first-child
{
    border-right:2px solid #000;
    text-align:right;
}
table td
{
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GRX99/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you used table tags, you can turn them into regular tags and use display:table / table-cell :

demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEBkA
HTML BLOCK for your title > content . use as many as needed.

```
<article>
  <h1>titre</h1>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>and text again</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

and minimal CSS:

```
article {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
/* tune next 2 rules */
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
article h1,
article div {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:0.5em;
}
article h1 {
  width:15%;
  border-right:solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something fluid, Bootstrap inspired.

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
      <p>Title A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <p>Very long content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
      <p>Title B</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <p>Another very long content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
}
.span2 {
  width: 20%;
}
.span10 {
  width: 80%;
}
.span2 p {
  float: right;
}
```

You have to adjust margins/paddings, but that's it.